# React.JS- Compare 2 arrays of objects and remove duplications with no ID

Tags: arrays, reactjs, javascript-objects

I got the following arrays:

```
arr1=[
{certification_Id: "***111"
domain_Name: ".com"
id: 3103
lastUpdate: "2020-05-19T17:03:50.000Z"
lineComment: "noLineComment"
product: "app1"
product_Id: 52
publisher_Id: "***11"
},

{
certification_Id: "***222"
domain_Name: ".com"
id: 3062
lastUpdate: "2020-05-18T11:18:58.000Z"
lineComment: "noLineComment"
product: "app1"
product_Id: 52
publisher_Id: "***123"
},

{
certification_Id: "***456"
domain_Name: ".com"
id: 3002
lastUpdate: "2020-05-18T11:18:58.000Z"
lineComment: "noLineComment"
product: "app1"
product_Id: 12
publisher_Id: "***333"
},
.......// and goes on
]
```

```
arr2=[
{certification_Id: "***111"
domain_Name: ".com"
id: Null
lastUpdate: "2020-06-20T17:03:50.000Z"
lineComment: "noLineComment"
product: "app1"
product_Id: 52
publisher_Id: "***11"
},

{certification_Id: "***222"
domain_Name: ".com"
id: Null
lastUpdate: "2020-06-21T17:03:50.000Z"
lineComment: "noLineComment"
product: "app1"
product_Id: 52
publisher_Id: "***123"
},

{certification_Id: "***33"
domain_Name: ".com"
id: Null
lastUpdate: "2020-06-20T17:03:50.000Z"
lineComment: "noLineComment"
product: "app1"
product_Id: 52
publisher_Id: "***33"
},
]
```

Can you please advise how can I merge into new array (lets say arr3) the objects that shares the same fields?
certification_Id, lineComment, domain_Name, product_Id.

I also have to insert to the new array the objects that doesn't share the same fields.

The final array have to look like this:

```
arr3= [
{certification_Id: "***111",
domain_Name: ".com",
id: 3103 (from arr1),
lastUpdate: "2020-06-20T17:03:50.000Z" (the most updated one from arr2),
lineComment: "noLineComment",
product: "app1",
product_Id: 52,
publisher_Id: "***11",
},

{
certification_Id: "***222"
domain_Name: ".com"
id: 3062 (from arr1)
lastUpdate: "2020-06-21T17:03:50.000Z" (the most updated one from arr2),
lineComment: "noLineComment"
product: "app1"
product_Id: 52
publisher_Id: "***123"
},

{
certification_Id: "***456"
domain_Name: ".com"
id: 3002
lastUpdate: "2020-05-18T11:18:58.000Z"
lineComment: "noLineComment"
product: "app1"
product_Id: 12
publisher_Id: "***333"
},

{certification_Id: "***33"
domain_Name: ".com"
id: Null
lastUpdate: "2020-06-20T17:03:50.000Z"
lineComment: "noLineComment"
product: "app1"
product_Id: 52
publisher_Id: "***33"
},
]
```

I tried using .map function, but it doesn't work for me.
Thanks for the helpers!!

Comment: The objects should be merged if they're exactly the same or some or their key-value pairs?

Comment: They should be merged if the keys "certification_Id", "domain_Name", "lineComment", "product", "product_Id" and "publisher_id" are identical. @Muneeb